# Spatial Indexing with SQL and Node

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, bookshelf.js, geohashing

I'm about to start a Node.js with a lot of POI (point of Interest) that will be saved on SQL database.

Is there a way to make proximity searches (ie find all POI near a given point within a given range) easily with SQL and Node? I would like to use geohash algorithm + bookshelf for ORM but I can't find any document on the Internet explaining how to start.

Mongodb has a geo spatial index. I would like the same thing but with SQL.

Any help would be welcome

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a real question - of course it is possible! However, you may achieve different performance using different solutions and with different complexity. Perhaps if you reformulate your question we could be more helpful.

Comment: What kind of infos would you need?

Answer (score 0):

Geohash is simple translate the points to a binary and interleave it. Treat it as base-4 number. Try the Microsoft Bing tiling system. It has some free code example.